# How can I extract data from "List <Contact>" of object and paste it into file.txt in C#?

Tags: c#

```
static List<Contact> ListOfContact = new List<Contact>(); //Sorce of data: 
    
public void SaveContactToFile() //method to save a data
{
    try
    {
        FileName = @"contacts.txt";
        // Check if file already exists. If no, create it.     
        if (!File.Exists(FileName))
        {
            File.Create(FileName);

            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(FileName))
            {
                foreach (String s in ListOfContact.verbList)
                    tw.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }      
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the of the ListOfContact data, and example of how you would like it to be written to the file ? The title suggests you are trying to write the entire object to the file, while the code suggests you are simply writing a single property on the object to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's so much missing in your code. Firstly `ListOfContact` is a list but you're trying to access `verbList` from it, which doesn't make sense.

Here's an example you can use...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Contact> Contacts = new List<Contact>{
                new Contact("John", "000-000-0000"),
                new Contact("Peter", "000-000-0001"),
                new Contact("George", "000-000-0001")
            };

            var fileName = "contacts.txt";

            //FileStream file = File.Create(fileName);

            Console.WriteLine("Writting to File");
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);

            using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fileName)))
            {
                foreach(var contact in Contacts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(contact.Print());
                    writer.WriteLine(contact.Print());
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Complete...");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class Contact
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }

            public Contact(string name, string number)
            {
                Name = name;
                Number = number;
            }

            public string Print()
            {
                return $"{Name} - {Number}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is functioning. You example is great help ! :))

Answer (score 0):

Your *ListOfContact* is a list of Contact instances. The list itself has no *verbList* member. Therefore, the code in your question will not even compile.

If you want to access the *verbList* member of each Contact instance, iterate over the list and access the *verbList* member **for each** Contact instance:

```cs
foreach (var contactInstance in ListOfContact)
{
    ... do stuff with contactInstance.verbList ...
}
```